# Passing SASS variable through module scss files

Tags: css, sass, next.js

I have set up my Base.scss file in my NextJS project as following:

```
$primary: "--primary";
$secondary: "--secondary";
$gradient: "--gradient";

:root {
  #{$primary}: #ececec;
  #{$secondary}: #444;
  #{$gradient}: linear-gradient(to right, #eacda3, #d6ae7b);
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  #{$primary}: #444;
  #{$secondary}: #ececec;
  #{$gradient}: linear-gradient(to right, #eacda3, #d6ae7b);
}

html,
body {
  color: var(--primary);
...
```

This works fine as long as I import my Base.scss to any SCSS file, but I get error if I try to pass my Base.scss to a *file*.module.scss.
How could I still import my variable even in module files?

I found solution and what I had to do is pass the [data-theme="dark"] to the file I wanted to style with my theme.
For example:

```
.btn {
  color: $color-dark;

  &:hover {
    color: $color-theme;
    border: 1px solid $color-theme;
  }
}

[data-theme="dark"] .btn {
  color: $color-light;
  border: 1px solid $color-light;

  &:hover {
    color: $color-theme;
    border: 1px solid $color-theme;
  }
}
```

This way my theme hook in NextJS recognizes the data and changes the theme.

Comment: Turn your `Base.scss` into a purely `silent` file. A file that only contains scss code that produce no css output: variable declarations and functions and mixins.

Comment: Let's say I do that and how am I supposed to pass variable from root file to module files? The ultimate goal is to make root have a variable and that variable is passed everywhere else, or am I missing something?

Comment: You seem to confuse compile time variable resolution and runtime variable resolution: sass variables like `$foo` are resolved during compile time; css-custom-variables like `--foo` are resolved during runtime, depending on DOM element nesting. You only want one place in your application code that adds the `:root` rule (probably the App.js or some entry point like that), not every sub-component.